# ASP.NET MVC4 n-Tier Architecture: best approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, n-tier-architecture

I developing a 3 tier architecture for an MVC4 webapp + EntityFramwork5.
I want to keep separete the layer, so only DAL knows that I'm using EF, for example.

Actually I have a lot of classes to manage that:

**DAL**

1. Entity POCO
2. Entity DataContext : DbContext
3. Entity Repository

**BL**

1. Entity ViewModel
2. Entity Service(instantiate Entity Repository)

**WEB**

1. Entity Controllers (instantiate Entity Service)

This is working but is quite hard to mantain. I was thinking to remove the Entity Repository in DAL and use directly the DataContext (if I'm not wrong, after all DbContext has been desingned to be a Repository and a Unit of Work), but that will force me to add a reference to EntityFramework.dll in my BL. Is not a big issue, but I0m not sure it is the best choice.

Any advice?

(I hope I gave enough informations, if you need more, just ask)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why u mention it is hard to maintain ur project. What layer do u think is it tough to maintain ?

Comment: For example, if I add a field to a POCO, I'll need to update the datacontext (not always), the dal repository, the BL view model, the BL service .. not few .. but probably is a must in this structure (or a desing error)

Comment: hi @Davide, u could apply some GOF design patterns for ur project as well. For example, if you could add a field to a POCO, u can use "Builder" pattern :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En) [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434282/A-N-Tier-Architecture-Sample-with-ASP-NET-MVC3-WCF) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1669618.aspx/1) article.

> ```
> An experienced Architect does not need to go through every single step in the book to get a reasonable design done for a small web
> ```
>
> application. Such Architects can use their experience to speed up the
>   process. Since I have done similar web applications before and have
>   understood my deliverable, I am going to take the faster approach to
>   get the initial part of our DMS design done. That will hopefully
>   assist me to shorten the length of this article.
>
> ```
> For those who do not have experience, let me briefly mention the general steps that involved in architecturing a software below...
>
> Understand the initial customer requirement - Ask questions and do research to further elaborate the requirement
> Define the process flow of the system preferably in visual (diagram) form. I usually draw a process-flow diagram here. In my
> ```
>
> effort, I would try to define the manual version of the system first
>   and then would try to convert that into the automated version while
>   identifying the processes and their relations. This process-flow
>   diagram that we draw here can be used as the medium to validate the
>   captured requirements with the customer too.
>       Identify the software development model that suite your requirements
>       When the requirements are fully captured and defined before the design start, you can use the 'Water-Fall' model. But when the
>   requirements are undefined, a variant of 'Spiral' can be used to deal
>   with that.
>       When requirements are not defined, the system gets defined while it is being designed. In such cases, you need to keep adequate spaces
>   in respective modules, which later expansions are expected.
>       Decide what architecture to be used. In my case, to design our Document Management System (DMS), I will be using a combination of
>   ASP.NET MVC and Multitier Architecture (Three Tier Variant).
>       Analyze the system and identify its modules or sub systems.
>       Pick one sub system at a time and further analyze it and identify all granular level requirements belonging to that part of the systems.
>       Recognize the data entities and define the relationships among entities (Entity Relationship Diagram or ER Diagram). That can
>   followed by identifying the business entities (Some business entities
>   directly map with the classes of your system) and define the business
>   process flow.
>       Organized your entities. This is where you normalize your database, and decide what OOP concepts and design pattern to be used
>   etc.
>       Make your design consistent. Follow the same standards across all modules and layers. This includes streamlining the concepts (as an
>   example, if you have used two different design patterns in two
>   different modules to achieve the same goal, then pick the better
>   approach and use that in both the places), and conventions used in the
>   project.
>       Tuning the design is the last part of the process. In order to do this, you need to have a meeting with the project team. In that
>   meeting you need to present your design to your team and make them ask
>   questions about it. Take this as an opportunity to honestly evaluate/
>   adjust your design.

Comment: Would you please state clearly that this is a long quote from your first reference and also include the numbered list? Thanks. It's a good thing you didn't give a link-only answer.